# Javascript spring physics: Apply direction vector to spring

Tags: javascript, math, physics

I'm implementing spring physics in Javascript, inspired by [this blog post](http://ghoscher.me/2013/03/02/simple-spring-physics/). My system uses Hooke's Law formula to calculate spring forces:

```
F = -k(|x|-d)(x/|x|) - bv
```

I made [a CodePen](http://codepen.io/andrewray/pen/epGyob?editors=001) that shows the implementation of a spring between two points. The CodePen has two points connected by a spring, and every 2 seconds the point positions are randomized. You can see the points bounce on the spring towards each other.

If you look at the source, you can see I've defined a direction vector for my spring:

```
var spring = {
    length: 100,
    direction: {
        x: 1, y: 1
    }
};
```

**I'm trying to make it so that the spring always "resolves" in this direction.** Put another way, I'd like the spring to always be "pointing" up and to the right. If this were implemented in the CodePen, it means the resting orientation of the points would **always be the green point on the bottom left, and the blue point on the top right**. No matter where the points start, they should end up in the following orientation (which matches the direction vector):

[image: Spring Hell]

I've tried multiplying the normals by the spring vector:

```
norm1 = multiplyVectors( normalize( sub1 ), spring.direction ),
```

However this is a noop because the vector is `(1,1)`. I've been hacking on this system for a few days now and I'm stuck. How can I constrain my 2d spring to a specific direction?

Comment: I've come up with something like this... basically take two springs: one in the y (bending sideways) and one in the x, where the x/y system is rotated to match the normal of your spring. Apply each of those forces independently and see what happens. That means you need another `k` for the sideways bend, but I think it's pretty reasonable.

Comment: As in two springs connected always at right angles? This is an interesting idea but it may be (i'm not sure) fundamentally different than a spring at an angle. For instance, a spring sticking out of a wooden block 45 degrees up and to the right behaves differently than a spring going straight to the right connected to a spring going straight up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring forces are central just like gravity, which means that the total angular momentum of the system is conserved. Since you start with zero initial velocities, the angular momentum of the system is initially zero. The spring interaction keeps it zero, therefore the final orientation of the spring equals its initial orientation - the weights only move along the line connecting them.

To have the system rotate into the desired final position, you should also apply torque. The easiest way is to give the blue weight a positive charge and the green weight a negative one and then apply a constant external field in direction `(1,1)`. That way the two charges will form a dipole and the interaction with the external field will generate the desired torque.

I don't get along with JavaScript, but I tried to write something based on your initial code [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdXbeZ?editors=001). The force that an external field with intensity `E` exerts on charge `q` is `F = q * E`, with both `F` and `E` being vectors. By adjusting `q` and `E` you can control how quickly the dipole will orient in the direction of the external field.

The force now becomes **F** = -k(|x|-d)(**x**/|x|) + q**E** - b**v**.

This has the probably undesired side effect that the final length of the spring will be slightly longer by `delta`, where `delta = 2 * |q||E| / k`. You can always adjust for that by reducing the length of the spring. Also, there is a little problem with that approach. Namely, there are two equilibrium states: one with the dipole facing the direction of the field (stable equilibrium) and one with the dipole facing the opposite direction (unstable equilibrium). A bit of random noise in the initial steps of the simulation will prevent the dipole from being trapped into the latter state.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work and is a bit confusing. You can see I tried your formula in an updated example http://codepen.io/andrewray/pen/JYregB?editors=001 `pos2 = addVectors( node1.offset, multiplyScalar( spring.direction, 1 / spring.length ) ),`

Comment: You seem to have changed the code that computes the forces. What I have described is how to generate the initial positions and should therefore be in `randomizePointPositions()`. Or may be I don't properly understand your question. Do you want to start with completely random initial positions and have the spring system end up in the desired direction? This won't be possible given the spring force alone, unless the initial configuration is already aligned with that direction.

Comment: Yes, I want to start with completely random initial positions, and have the force of the spring resolve to a specific orientation.

Comment: @AndyRay, just charge the weights and add a constant electric field. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: A simple yet powerful solution, and it works great for my application and multiple springs. Thank you!